# How to test exception raising in Rails/RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

There is the following code:

```
def index
    @car_types = car_brand.car_types
end

def car_brand
    CarBrand.find(params[:car_brand_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    raise Errors::CarBrandNotFound.new 
end
```

I want to test it through RSpec. My code is:

```
it 'raises CarBrandNotFound exception' do
    get :index, car_brand_id: 0
    expect(response).to raise_error(Errors::CarBrandNotFound)
end
```

CarBrand with id equaling 0 doesn't exist, therefore my controller code raises Errors::CarBrandNotFound, but my test code tells me that nothing was raised. How can I fix it? What do I wrong?

Answer (score 192):

Use `expect{}` instead of `expect()`.

Example:

```
it do 
  expect { response }.to raise_error(Errors::CarBrandNotFound)
end
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this solves the issue because the {} syntax creates a block to monitor for the given exception to be raised. MiniTest has similar syntax requirements when checking that a block of code raises an exception.

Comment: I can't believe it. 1 hour of trying and it's just turning `( )` into `{ }`! Thank you so much

Comment: I wasn't able to get this method working in Rails 7

Answer (score 156):

In order to spec error handling, your expectations need to be set on a block; evaluating an object cannot raise an error.

So you want to do something like this:

```
expect {
  get :index, car_brand_id: 0
}.to raise_error(Errors::CarBrandNotFound)
```

I am a bit surprised that you don't get any exception bubbling up to your spec results, though.

Comment: @jakob-s the expect error behaviour that you're using here doesn't work on controller requests. The `get :index, car_brand_id: 0` itself doesn't raise an error.

Comment: @RicardoOtero Things might have changed, but for what it's worth, it does for me: https://gist.github.com/koppen/0e1d0894a908a3768847. But certainly, something in the stack might be handling the error before it bubbles up to the spec runner.

Comment: This is the right answer for current rspec versions ans should be voted up

Comment: That is correct. The correct form to to test exceptions is using {} instead of () on except method.

Answer (score 18):

`get :index` will never raise an exception - it will rather set response to be an 500 error some way as a real server would do.

Instead try:

```
it 'raises CarBrandNotFound exception' do
  controller.params[:car_brand_id] = 0
  expect{ controller.car_brand }.to raise_error(Errors::CarBrandNotFound)
end
```

Comment: I'm glad that someone mentioned this! :) Jakob tried to educate them that it will never raise an exception in the most upvoted answer but he was faced with some incorrect resistance. 

Answer (score 7):

If you want to test the message that comes along with the exception, you can also do something like this:

```rb
it do 
  expect { response }.to raise_error(Errors::CarBrandNotFound, "Ford not found")
end
```