# Testing methods that eventually throw an exception in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, exception

I've got a method as follows:

```
 if response.fetch('ok')
    response.fetch(response_key) { [] }
  elsif response.fetch('error') == 'token_revoked'
    ErrorReporter.increment('access_revoked', source: { account_id: account_id }, sporadic: true)
    fail(RemoteService::AccessRevoked, 'Our access to your account was revoked, please re-authorize.')
  else
    ErrorReporter.increment(
      'bad_request',
      source: {
        account_id: account_id
        error: response.fetch('error')
      },
      sporadic: true
    )
    fail(RemoteService::InvalidRequest, 'Something went wrong communicating with the remote service, please try again')
  end
```

And I'm trying to test the scenario when the request returns with the `token_revoked` error.  I'd like to ensure the test specifies that in this scenario, that we report the error to our ErrorReporting service.

So, my spec looks like this:

```
it 'records the failure with our error reporting service' do
  expect(ErrorReporter).to receive(:increment).with(
    'bad_request',
     source: {
       account_id:  1
     },
     sporadic: true
   )

   available_channels.fetch
end
```

However, this spec always fails, because after the call is made to the ErrorReporter, the code immediately calls `fail` which makes my spec fail.  Does anyone have any idea how I can verify that the call to my error reporter is made while handling the inevitable exception that I know the code is now going to throw?

Comment: Does this help? [how-to-test-exception-raising-in-rails-rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141601/how-to-test-exception-raising-in-rails-rspec)

Comment: No, that doesn't help, the spec after that handles the fact that I expect an exception to be thrown, here I'm trying to assert that we send the error to our service _before_ the exception is thrown.

Comment: Just wrap the call to `available_channels.fetch` in a `begin ... rescue RemoteService::InvalidRequest` block.

Comment: @Stefan beat me to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [expect errors](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) to be raised in code. In order for the exception to be caught by RSpec, you need to use a block as follows:

```
it 'records the failure with our error reporting service' do
  expect(ErrorReporter).to receive(:increment).with(
    'bad_request',
    source: {
      account_id:  1
    },
    sporadic: true
  )

  expect { available_channels.fetch }
    .to raise_error RemoteService::InvalidRequest
end
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I also concluded, thank you for confirming this approach might be the best way to handle it.

Answer (score -2):

The exception causes your example to fail because it is not rescued. To prevent the error, you can wrap the method call in a `begin ... rescue` block:

```
it 'records the failure with our error reporting service' do
  expect(ErrorReporter).to receive(:increment).with(
    'bad_request',
     source: {
       account_id:  1
     },
     sporadic: true
   )

   begin
     available_channels.fetch
   rescue => RemoteService::InvalidRequest
     # would cause the example to fail
   end
end
```

In another example, you should also `expect` the error to be raised.