# Rspec: How to test a method that raises an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a SubscriptionHandler class with a call method that creates a pending subscription, attempts to bill the user and then error out if the billing fails. The pending subscription is created regardless of whether or not the billing fails

```
class SubscriptionHandler

  def initialize(customer, stripe_token)
    @customer = customer
    @stripe_token = stripe_token
  end

  def call
    create_pending_subscription
    attempt_charge!
    upgrade_subscription
  end

  private

  attr_reader :stripe_token, :customer

  def create_pending_subscription
   @subscription = Subscription.create(pending: true, customer_id: customer.id)
  end

  def attempt_charge!
    StripeCharger.new(stripe_token).charge!  #raises FailedPaymentError
  end

  def upgrade_subscription
   @subscription.update(pending: true)
  end

 end
```

Here is what my specs look like:

```
describe SubscriptionHandler do

  describe "#call" do
    it "creates a pending subscription" do
      customer = create(:customer)
      token = "token-xxx"
      charger = StripeCharger.new(token)
      allow(StripeCharger).to receive(:new).and_return(charger)
      allow(charger).to receive(:charge!).and_raise(FailedPaymentError)
      handler = SubscriptionHandler.new(customer, token)

      expect { handler.call }.to change { Subscription.count }.by(1) # Fails with FailedPaymentError
    end
  end
end
```

But this does not change the subscription count, it fails with the FailedPaymentError. Is there a way to check that the subscription count increases without the spec blowing up with FailedPaymentError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Rspec compound expectations for this

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/compound-expectations

So I'll re-write your expectation to something like this:

```
expect { handler.call }.
 to raise_error(FailedPaymentError).
 and change { Subscription.count }.by(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this

```
expect{ handler.call }.to raise_error FailedPaymentError
```

Should work.

If you don't want to raise error at all then you can remove this line, and return a valid response instead

```
allow(charger).to receive(:charge!).and_raise(FailedPaymentError)
```

More info - [How to test exception raising in Rails/RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141601/how-to-test-exception-raising-in-rails-rspec)

Official RSpec docs

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-error

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I want to test that the Subscription count actually increases